# Netiquette for summarizing other answers in a new answer

Tags: discussion, answers, policy, canonical-questions, copyright

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights) is the go-to duplicate thread for any flight-search engine question on Travel SE. It has 10+ answers and at least for me (and I guess fresh users as well) that is too much scrolling down at first.

I thus summarized the websites suggested in all the answers in a kind of [overview answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62685/32134). I tried to briefly list the functionalities of all websites there, in many cases with less detail than the original answers (that might e.g. contain screenshots, etc).

It has been pointed out in a comment (and I see the point) that my answer contains mostly duplicate information so I am asking:

1. Was it impolite or useless of mine to compile that overview and post it as an answer?
2. Do you suggest changes? Should I delete the answer? Should I include links to each original answer? Should I make it Community Wiki? Can I improve the answer in some way?

Comment: I agree with the comment. Your answer is a great summary, but does not add any significantly new information and it too will become out-of-date after a while.  On the other hand, there's no great harm done and at this point you can step back and let the darwinian process of up/down votes work their magic.

Comment: You can maybe convert the answer into a [FAQ-like post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), in which you link the other answers to the question. Right now you are linking the websites directly.

Comment: @JoErNanO, could you elaborate on the FAQ thing? I'm linking to pages directly because that's where a user/reader wants to go to I assume. E.g. a link to that answer at the end of each bullet point?

Comment: Rather than pointing at the site, point at the answer describing that site. Does this make any sense? :)

Comment: @JoErNanO thanks :) I'll try to find a way to point both to site and answer as I think a user might be interested in both.

Comment: +1 to the question, no matter where the consensus ends I think it's good to ask about that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think summarising is great in general. I vaguely recall some FAQ encouraging it. After all, the whole point of the Q&A format is to get comprehensive, self-contained answers to each question, not bits and pieces of info and people reacting to each other as in a forum. Theoretically, if there can't be a single answer solving the problem described in the question, then that question should even be closed (that's the reason why subjective, open-ended list questions are frowned upon)!

If you are only doing a summary or concerned that your answer looks too much like a rip-off of other answers there are several things you can do to counter that impression, e.g. add a bit of structure, write a good description of each solution or compare them to each other, explicitly acknowledge previous answers (or even comments) in the text or mark your answer as a community wiki. As you discovered yourself, you can even link to other answers if need be… [Here is how I have done it in another case](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/is-there-a-flight-search-engine-that-combines-flights-from-different-airlines/26888#26888) and it has been relatively well received.

Yet another option is to open a new question to put your answer. You have to make sure you're really adding something (a clearer or more generic question and a really comprehensive answer) otherwise people are going to see it as a ploy to increase your reputation but there is nothing wrong with creating a question and answering it at the same time, if it allows you to better address a problem. [Here is an attempt at doing this for a completely different topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area).

(I haven't looked at your answer in great details, it seems fine to me but maybe it could still be improved, the point is that there is nothing wrong with summarising/creating an overview in principle.)